# WPF How to use MahApps.Metro MessagBox in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

In UserControl,I can not use the method ShowMessageAsync().What can I do to use it.

Comment: Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the parent `MetroWindow`. You could do this using the `Window.GetWindow` method:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;
    }

    private async void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Metro.Controls.MetroWindow window = Window.GetWindow(this) as Metro.Controls.MetroWindow;
        if(window != null)
        {
            await window.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");
        }
    }
}
```

You always need a reference to a `MetroWindow` to be able to show a dialog using the `ShowMessageAsync` method in `MahApps.Metro`.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow